# On the number of irreducible component(s) of an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that any affine algebraic set in an affine n space(which is Noetherian ) is finite union of irreducible closed subsets(called irreducible components of the affine algebraic set) upto some condition(and the same is true in projective case also).Now the proof the fact that we naturally encounter on the book is kind of existence proof.So the immediate set of questions are

1)Is there any constructive proof available of the fact where given a general algebraic set it describes explicitly how to find out the irreducible components?

2)If the answer of first one is in negative then can we atleast have an idea (atleast intuitive) of the number of irreducible components of a given algebraic set?

For example, I was doing a very specific problem where it asks to find  3 irreducible components of a given algebraic set and I observed that there are
exactly 3 distinct types of points in the algebraic set which is matching with the number of irreducible components.Is the above special case a pure coincidence or this kind of intuition (may be modified intuition) can still be applied in general situation to predict/guess the number of irreducible components of an algebraic set?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: This is generally pretty hard and requires some ingenuity. (Some people like to say that applying AG to basic examples is somehow much harder than learning the general theory)

Comment: Primary decomposition of the ideal defining the affine algebraic set will give the irreducible components.

Comment: @krish I just looked in the book by Atiyah and Macdonald ,there it is written that in general primary decomposition need not exist.I do not know whether the ring being Noetherian is a sufficient condition for existence of primary decomposition or not.Even in Noetherian case is there a generic strategy available to find out such a decomposition or we have to do it case by case basis?

Comment: Every ideal in a Noetherian ring has a primary decomposition.  See Theorem 7.13 (p. 83) in Atiyah-Macdonald.  However, I'm not sure Krish's comment answers your question, since the authors do not provide an algorithm to compute the primary decomposition.  Really to get the irreducible components of an affine algebraic set, you just need the minimal or associated primes, not the full primary decomposition.

Comment: There certainly are algorithms to compute primary decompositions and minimal primes in polynomial rings (they are implemented in Macaulay2 and Magma) using Gröbner bases, but I'm not familiar with their inner workings. [Here is a reference](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.190.8262&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that may be helpful.